# @JoinColumn and mappedBy for owning side and reverse side

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I have question regarding the `@JoinColumn` and `mappedBy` in hibernate, after i read through so many posts in stackoverflow and other blogs, i still confuse.

Take this as an example, each employee has many emails and many emails can be owned by one employee :

[image]

**First statement:** **Email** is the **owning side** because it has the foreign key to the Employee table, normally in a relationship, the "Many" side is the owning side.

In hibernate, for bidirectional relationship:

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
}
```

**Email**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
public class Email{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
}
```

So from what i read, normally the `@JoinColumn` is at the owning side, where the `mappedBy` is at the reverse side.

But i also read from somewhere that `@JoinColumn` is at reverse side where `mappedBy` is at owning side.

I am confused, which is the appropriate one?

Answer (score 3):

@JoinColumn annotation is maintained in the class which owns the foreign key. As per your code, Email class would be using @JoinColumn annotation specifying foreign key reference. It actually contributes to the mapping between two tables because you specify the bridging column name "employee_id" through this annotation.

On the other hand, mappedBy is just used to enable bidirectional mapping between the entities.So, it should be used on the reverse side (non owning class).

Answer (score 2):

User -> Asset (One to Many)

**Employee.java**

```
 @JsonBackReference
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<Asset> asset = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Asset.java**

```
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
```

---

`@JoinColumn`

- If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping using a foreign
  key mapping strategy, the foreign key column is in the table of the
  source entity or embeddable.
- If the join is for a unidirectional OneToMany mapping using a foreign
  key mapping strategy, the foreign key is in the table of the target
  entity.
- If the join is for a ManyToMany mapping or for a OneToOne or
  bidirectional ManyToOne/OneToMany mapping using a join table, the
  foreign key is in a join table.
- If the join is for an element collection, the foreign key is in a
  collection table.

---

`mappedBy`

Whether to apply the remove operation to entities that have been removed from the relationship and to cascade the remove operation to those entities